# Surge Protectors - Wall Outlet Plug vs. Stationary Surge Protector

Tags: power-management, ups, surge-protection

While the former will cost 3 times less:

[image]

The latter will cost more:

[image]

**Question:**

Are both almost the same or the latter is better (which i suppose is judging by price)?

Answer (score 3):

it depends on what you are using it for.  Surge protectors simply protect from power surges.  Power cleaners and UPS's offer more features such as electrical noise cleaning, protection from a dip in current, etc.

If you are not experiencing any issues with your hardware due to electrical inconsistencies, than a simple surge protector is all you need.

Comment: A simple surge-suppressor is basically just a fuse/circuit-breaker, while a bulky UPS/cleaner has advanced systems to ensure that your electronics get a smooth, steady, consistent current, often with status logs, alerts, and feedback. Like Keltari said, it depends on what you are trying to protect. You can plug cheap stuff into a surge-protector, and expensive stuff into a stabilizer/UPS. As a middle ground, you can get some devices from the likes of APC and their ilk that costs somewhere in the middle and has advanced protection, but leaves out the UPS (and perhaps some other fancier) parts.

Comment: So i can use cleaner and laptop battery to create UPS like effect?